# Delimit and split array into new array's

Tags: php, arrays, split, delimiter

**I have the following array:**

```
$data = ['user_first_name:string', 'user_last_name:string', 'user_email:email', 'user_password:password'];
```

How do I convert the above string to multiple array's, each containing the first part as index[0] and the second as index[1];

so "user_first_name:string", should be converted to an array , like:

```
array("user_first_name", "string")
```

**Some background information:**
The first part of each value ("user_first_name") references a POST field and the second part references the method to use in my Validate class. For example: user_first_name is a field in my POST and should pass through my string filter method.

Comment: Use `explode()`.

Comment: I'd think that `array("user_first_name"=>"string", "user_last_name"=>"string")` would be a more sensible structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_map with explode:

```
<?php

$data = ['user_first_name:string', 'user_last_name:string', 'user_email:email', 'user_password:password'];

$data = array_map(function($item) {
    return explode(':', $item);
}, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_first_name
            [1] => string
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_last_name
            [1] => string
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_email
            [1] => email
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_password
            [1] => password
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = [
    'user_first_name:string', 
    'user_last_name:string', 
    'user_email:email', 
    'user_password:password'
];

foreach($data as $pair)
    $output[] = explode(':', $pair);

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
    0 => 'user_first_name',
    1 => 'string',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    0 => 'user_last_name',
    1 => 'string',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
    0 => 'user_email',
    1 => 'email',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
    0 => 'user_password',
    1 => 'password',
    ),
)
```